# Health Monitoring is not logging errors when CustomError is set to "On" or "RemoteOnly"

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, health-monitoring

I am using Health Monitoring for catching all errors and sending them to email. While it works in the development environment it did not when I deploy it in Prod. The only difference being the "customerrors" set to "on/off". So, I verified it again and it seems it will not log when the custom errors is set to "On/RemoteOnly". Below is part of my configuration in question.

Is there a workaround to this issue? Thanks.

```
<healthMonitoring enabled="true">
  <eventMappings>
    <clear />
    <add name="All Errors" type="System.Web.Management.WebBaseErrorEvent"
     startEventCode="0" endEventCode="2147483647" />
  </eventMappings>

  <providers>
    <clear />

    <add
     name="SimpleMailWebEventProvider"
     type="System.Web.Management.SimpleMailWebEventProvider"
     to="dev@net"
     from="de@net"
     buffer="false"
    />
  </providers>

  <rules>
    <clear />

    <add name="All Errors Default" eventName="All Errors" provider="SimpleMailWebEventProvider"
profile="Default" minInstances="1" maxLimit="Infinite" minInterval="00:00:00" />
  </rules>
</healthMonitoring>
```

--update
This is MVC3 project

Comment: Can you create some code in your production environment that sends an email via your smtp server using the same to & from email addresses you are using in your health monitoring setup?

Comment: Yes, it is not a problem with mail. When I tested it on local machine with Custom Error set to "On" it did not raise any error events.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In an ASP.NET MVC 3 project you will have a global `HandleError` action filter registered by default in `global.asax.cs`:

```
public static void RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilterCollection filters)
{
    filters.Add(new HandleErrorAttribute());
}
```

This attribute gets applied to *every* controller action and if `customErrors` are set to `On` only the custom error page is displayed and the exception that occured in a controller action is marked as handled. ASP.NET Health Monitoring doesn't see this exception anymore and can't log it.

An approach to use Health Monitoring together with the `HandleError` attribute and a custom error page is described [here](http://weblogs.asp.net/awilinsk/archive/2008/12/11/handleerrorattribute-and-health-monitoring.aspx) and [here](http://aspnetresources.com/blog/health_monitoring_webforms_vs_mvc) and [here](http://mattfrear.com/2011/01/28/mvc3-logging-exceptions/):

You create a custom error attribute derived from `HandleError`:

```
public class HandleErrorHealthMonitoringAttribute : HandleErrorAttribute
{
    public override void OnException(ExceptionContext filterContext)
    {
        // Do the default, i.e. show custom error page if custom errors are on
        base.OnException(filterContext);

        // Suppress raising the health monitoring event below if custom errors
        // are off. In that case health monitoring will receive the exception
        // anyway and raise the event
        if (!filterContext.HttpContext.IsCustomErrorEnabled)
            return;

        // Raise health monitoring event
        var errorEvent = new GenericWebRequestErrorEvent(
            "Unhandled exception occurred.", this,
            WebEventCodes.WebExtendedBase + 1, filterContext.Exception);

        errorEvent.Raise();
    }
}
```

And then register this attribute instead of default `HandleError`:

```
public static void RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilterCollection filters)
{
    filters.Add(new HandleErrorHealthMonitoringAttribute());
}
```

The `GenericWebRequestErrorEvent` is a custom error event derived from the base `WebRequestErrorEvent`. It doesn't do anything custom and only exists because `WebRequestErrorEvent` doesn't have any `public` constructors, so we can't use `var errorEvent = new WebRequestErrorEvent(...)`:

```
public class GenericWebRequestErrorEvent : WebRequestErrorEvent
{
    public GenericWebRequestErrorEvent(string message, object eventSource,
        int eventCode, Exception exception) :
        base(message, eventSource, eventCode, exception)
    {
    }

    public GenericWebRequestErrorEvent(string message, object eventSource,
        int eventCode, int eventDetailCode, Exception exception) :
        base(message, eventSource, eventCode, eventDetailCode, exception)
    {
    }
}
```

Note, that you will receive an email titled with `MyNamespace.GenericWebRequestErrorEvent` and not with `System.Web.Management.WebRequestErrorEvent` and the event code will always be `100001` (= `WebEventCodes.WebExtendedBase + 1`).